# Combine matrix column in one vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` of size 4x1 as shown below, what I want to do is to a have a vector `B` containing the elements of matrix `A`as shown here `B= 145, 144, 192, 145, 197, 307, 143, 198, 309` so if anyone could please advise

```
A=
145
[144;192]
[145;197;307]
[143;198;309]
```

Comment: Note that A is not actually a matrix, probably it is a cell array.

Comment: Please clarify how `A` was defined. As written your "matrix" is ragged (different number of elements per row) - that's not really how they work in Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that `A` is a cell array, not a matrix. In which case you can do the following:

```
B = [A{:}];
```

or, since the individual elements in `A` are column vectors in your example,

```
At = cellfun(@transpose, A, 'uniformoutput', false);
B = [At{:}];
```

Or just

```
B = vertcat(A{:});
```

(Thanks @horchler for reminding me of the simple...)

Comment: Or maybe `vertcat`. Who knows how that cell is oriented.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to transpose all your elements of A to be rows:

```
A = cellfun(@transpose, A,'UniformOutput', false)
```

Then horizontally concatenate (i.e. `[]`) a comma separated list (i.e. `{:}`):

```
B = [A{:}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` is defined like this:

```
A={145
[144;192]
[145;197;307]
[143;198;309]}
```

You can use vertical concatenation:

```
vertcat(A{:})'
```

If the vectors in A are transposed, you can use `[]` or `horzcat`